# Java Nio Zip file

Tags: java, nio

It seems a really stupid thing but I can't see what I am doing wrong.
I have a folder that contains several zip files. Every zip file contains at least one file named *sometingXYZsomething*. I want to read every file sometingXYZsomething without unzipping every single zip, so, on the fly let's say. 
My code is:

```
 try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(FOLDER_NAME)))
 {

    paths
      .filter(p -> p.toString().contains("XYZ"))
      .forEach(p -> readFileXYZ(Paths.get(p.getName())));

  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

And

```
private static void readFileXYZ(Path pathFile)
{    
  try {

    Files.lines(pathFile).forEach(System.out::println);   

  } catch (IOException ex) 
  {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

The test folder has one zip, that contains a txt document testFileXYZ.txt and I get this exception

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: testFileXYZ.txt
testFileXYZ.txt
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
```

How can I get a stream of the txt file in the zip without extracting it?

Comment: True, it is an extra step. I update the code

Answer (score 3):

The problem you've got is that you're not actually unzipping the content of the ZipFile. The ZipFile.stream() allows you to iterate through the Zip metadata (the list of file names in the Zip) but doesn't actually unzip the content for you to read. To do that, you need to use an InputStream acquired from the ZipFile, and then read that to get your content. I've provided an example of this below. There are other ways of doing this (e.g. using a ZipInputStream) but I wanted to base my example on the code you supplied. Hope this helps!

```
private static void openZip(String zipPath)
{
    try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipPath))
    {
        zipFile.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.toString().contains("XYZ"))
                .forEach(p -> readFileXYZ(p, zipFile));

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void readFileXYZ(ZipEntry zipEntry, ZipFile zipFile)
{
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry);
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        String line;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```